# Replacing errors with blank on M/ Power BI Advanced query editor?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a simple formula that working great, but I want to replace any errors with blank.

Can anybody please help me to change this?

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "AnnualBacklog", each if [AnnualThr] < [TotalRemaining] then [AnnualThr] else [TotalRemaining])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#"XYZ" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "AnnualBacklog", each if [AnnualThr] < [TotalRemaining] then [AnnualThr] else [TotalRemaining])

    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"XYZ", {{"AnnualBacklog", ""}})
in
    #"Replaced Errors"
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP will clarify, or perhaps it is a language issue, but I believe  `blank`= `""`  Your code is replacing the error with `space`